# Is it possible to change the orientation that filament is laid down for the top layer in Cura Slicer?

Tags: ultimaker-cura

In Cura Slicer, is it possible to change the direction that the filament is laid down when making the top layer?

[image]

For example, in the above picture the filiment is laid down at about 45 degrees to the X\Y axis. Can I make it 90 degrees?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Set "Top Surface Skin Layers" (roofing layers) to at least 1 and "Top Surface Skin Line Directions" to 0 or 90 as appropriate (instead of 45 and 135).

Comment: Which version did this feature appear in?

Comment: @Trish: Looks like 2.7, commit `26ac70d2bd` adds the config item to `fdmprinter.def.json`. This was in 2017, well before I used Cura or even a 3D printer.

Comment: @Trish: It's part of the general "roofing" feature of Cura, whose purpose is to let you use more visually appealing (or, if you're pushing the limits of your printer on top layers to the point that there are structural gaps, more structurally sound) speed, acceleration, line width, etc. settings for the last layer ot two at the top, without imposing that cost on however many top layers you need (typically 4-5 in my experience, maybe more with some combinations of layer height etc.)

Comment: Found it! it is a setting you need to enable first

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment in Trish's answer, a custom solution might be possible using g-code, but would likely be quite tedious. I have a (retired) client whose career spanned more years than I've been alive. He traversed his development from manual machining through punched cards/paper tape and through CAD/CAM, but always created the g-code from the ground up.

One could, for example, locate a CAM program with which one is comfortable and set about defining tool paths and related configurations. Fusion 360 may have a slicer feature in the non-free portion; I've not pursued that aspect of the software.

One could also examine the g-code generated for a specific layer and make appropriate adjustments to the direction of travel, extrusion commands, speed, etc.

An [Instructable](https://www.instructables.com/Manual-Gcode-for-3d-Stamp-Create-Square/) exists which describes a method to create a hollow cube for 3D printing, but it's severely limited in scope, in my opinion. It has triggered another thought, to use the g-code generated for laser cutting/engraving as a foundation for the above noted manual creation.

For example, a g-code based laser (i.e., GRBL) could be commanded to cut lines spaced apart by the filament width when placed by the printer, often 0.4 mm approximately. LightBurn software (multi-platform, 30-day free trial, supports GRBL) would allow you to experiment creating the initial code, which would then require manual editing for temperatures and extrusion rates.

This would require substantial experimentation and substantial time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes with a few tricks:

You could turn the item by 45°, then all layers are turned to follow the local X and Y-axis of the body itself, but not the global X and Y of the printer - there'll be a 45° conversion between the items local coordinates and the printers global ones.

Or you could choose a different upper layer pattern, for example concentric, for the upper and lowermost layer.

If you want to define a specific zig-zag direction, you need to go advanced mode, click the gear and enable "Top/Bottom Line Direction". This now allows altering the direction by setting an angle different from 45°/135°. The setting however is ignored if you don't use Lines or ZigZag

[image: the 4.8 setting that needs to be enabled]
[image: 4.8 look]